# Copying a line from one file to another in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to copy a line from file1 and write that line into line 10 of file2 using bash.

Here is what I have tried:

```
sed -e '10i' file2 <file1
```

Comment: @daOnlyDB Stop making troll edits. Thanks.

Comment: Is it the first line of file1 that you would like to copy? Does file1 only contain 1 line?

Comment: if the file2 has e.g. 20 lines, you want 1.) replace the line10 (so in the result you will still have 20 lines in the file2 OR 2.) insert the line after the line 9 (so the file2 will have 21 lines) ?  Example of the two input files and the wanted result would be the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$0}NR==FNR{next}FNR==10{print a}1' file1 file2
```

`NR` keeps a count of the overall line number. This is only equal to 1 for the first line of the first file. The contents of the line is stored in a variable `a`.

`FNR` keeps a count of the line number of the current file. `NR` and `FNR` are equal (i.e. we are in file1), `next` skips to the next line, which means that for every other line in the first file, nothing happens.

The final block is executed at line 10 of the second file, inserting the value of `a`. The `1` at the end is a common shorthand which means that every line of the file is printed.

Testing it out:

```
$ cat file1
line 1 in file1
line 2 in file1    
$ cat file2
line 1 in file2
line 2 in file2
line 3 in file2
line 4 in file2
line 5 in file2
line 6 in file2
line 7 in file2
line 8 in file2
line 9 in file2
line 10 in file2
$ awk 'NR==1{a=$0}NR==FNR{next}FNR==10{print a}1' file1 file2
line 1 in file2
line 2 in file2
line 3 in file2
line 4 in file2
line 5 in file2
line 6 in file2
line 7 in file2
line 8 in file2
line 9 in file2
line 1 in file1
line 10 in file2
```

To overwrite the original contents of file2, you can redirect the output to a temporary file like `awk '...' file1 file2 tmp && mv tmp file2`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you want your lines to come from and go to, but you could do this:

```
sed 'NUMq;d' file1 >>file2
```

replacing `NUM` with the number of the line you want from file1 to append to file2.

EDIT

I think this is what you want:

```
sed -i .bak "10 i\\
`sed 1q\;d file1`
" file2
```

Comment: I want to put line number 1 into line number 10 of file 2

Comment: @user2719058 the `1q` quits after the first line. If I wanted to extract a different line number, say 15, then `15q` would output the first 15 lines of the file.  In this case, the `;d` deletes everything but the last line. You're right, in the case of `1q;d` it's unnecessary, but you need it for `2q;d` and on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU `sed`, this:

```
sed -n '1p' choose-line-here.txt | sed -i '10r /dev/stdin' insert-here.txt
```

will insert line 1 from `choose-line-here.txt` after line 10 in `insert-here.txt`.

*Changing* line 10 seems to be trickier, surprisingly. I've come up with this so far:

```
sed -n 1p choose-line-here.txt |
sed -e '9!b' -e 'N;s/\n.*//;r /dev/stdin' insert-here.txt
```

The tricky part is, that the `r` command inserts the contents of `/dev/stdin`, that is, standard input, *after* the current line. If that is the line which is to be replaced, then I don't see a way to get rid of it without outputting a spare newline. Therefore the trick to start the insertion in the previous line, line 9 in this case.

A simpler solution for changing the target line is possible, if one relies on `sed` not counting the freshly read line from stdin:

```
sed -n 1p choose-line-here.txt |
sed -i -e '9r /dev/stdin' -e '10d' insert-here.txt
```

Comment: Good addition of the note. `after line 10`. To insert as line `10`, obviously change `10r` to `9r`. Good solution.

Comment: Well, the to-be-changed line somehow has to go away. But I've added a simpler solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Bash):

```
sed $'10{e sed "1!d" file1\n;d}' file2
```

or another way using a pipe:

```
sed '1!d' file1 | sed -e '10{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' file2
```

or a third way (perhaps more intuitively but only works for a singleton replacement line):

```
sed '10\c'$(sed '1!d' file1) file2
```